# rpc.h missing? Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04

I'm porting older in house software to 21.04. I run rpcgen without error, it creates a ".h" file that has the expected "#include <rpc/rpc.h>", but I cannot locate a package that actually contains the header file that rpcgen expects. Suggestions?

TIA.

Comment: Is the file there? it should be in /usr/include/rpc/rpc.h? it should be provided by the libc6-dev package.

Comment: libc6-dev is installed, the only file in /usr/include/rpc is netdb.h. "libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.33-0ubuntu5)".

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is provided by `libntirpc-dev`. So do a ...

```
sudo apt install libntirpc-dev
```

Then you may need to add `/usr/include/tirpc` to the `CPATH` environment variable.

[List of files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/libntirpc-dev/filelist)

Comment: There appears to be another (**n**ewer?) port [libntirpc-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/libntirpc-dev) as well...

Comment: good catch @steeldriver that one seems newer indeed :) changed it. thanks

Comment: IMHO it's worth mentioning both - since we don't know which might work for the OP's "older in house software"

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure those are "correct" rpc.h files. I'm wondering why rpcgen doesn't seem to know the "new" locations of the files. Adds a bit of work to the "make clean; make" workflow if I have to keep editing the resulting output files from rpcgen to correct the location of the header files.

Comment: @DonKrause I wonder if you can avoid editing the generated file(s) by passing a suitable value of CFLAGS to `make` ex. `make CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/ntirpc` ?

Comment: I installed libntirpc-dev but still having the same problem. can you help me?

Comment: I also installed libntirpc-dev and Im getting error it cant find fatal error: misc/abstract_atomic.h: No such file or directory

Comment: "misc/abstract_atomic.h"  https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-arm64/libntirpc-dev_3.0-0ubuntu2_arm64.deb.html it is in there.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes I have installed `libntirpc-dev` but C preprocessor cant find it, so I sym linked those files https://stackoverflow.com/a/75119175/3291092