# Fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory

Tags: snort, rpc

I am trying to install Snort on Ubuntu 21.04 from source files as per instructions on the Snort website. I have followed videos on Youtube and got past a number of issues, but I am stuck at:

```cpp
sp_rpc_check.c:32:10: fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #include <rpc/rpc.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [Makefile:478: sp_rpc_check.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/snort-2.9.18/src/detection-plugins'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:428: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/snort-2.9.18/src/detection-plugins'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:547: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/snort-2.9.18/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:505: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/snort-2.9.18'
make: *** [Makefile:370: all] Error 2
```

Have tried
`sudo apt install libntirpc-dev` as per another thread here on AskUbuntu.

I am relatively newbie. have done `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.

From  the snort website, https://www.snort.org/#get-started,  have done all of:

```sh
wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/daq-2.0.7.tar.gz
                      
wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/snort-2.9.18.tar.gz
tar xvzf daq-2.0.7.tar.gz
                      
cd daq-2.0.7
./configure && make && sudo make install
tar xvzf snort-2.9.18.tar.gz
                      
cd snort-2.9.18
```

but when running :

```sh
./configure --enable-sourcefire && make && sudo make install
```

get the error described above

I have also sorted libpcap, libpcre and dnet issues out. So it is just this rpc issue now. Thanks

Comment: You may find this recent Q&A helpful: [rpc.h missing? Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1360094/178692)

Comment: What was wrong with binary package https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/snort ?

Comment: I'll be honest , I can't remember if I tried this at first. But I just tried and I get:
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 8 not to upgrade. But; $ snort
Running in packet dump mode

        --== Initializing Snort ==--
Initializing Output Plugins!
pcap DAQ configured to passive.
Acquiring network traffic from "enp6s0".
ERROR: Can't start DAQ (-1) - socket: Operation not permitted!
Fatal Error, Quitting..

Answer (score 2):

my OS is Debian, you can:

1. Install the corresponding package with header files (what the **-dev** indicates).

```
sudo apt install libntirpc-dev
```

2.Find where all the header files live.

```
dpkg -L libntirpc-dev
```

You can see some outputs like this:

```
/usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/rpc.h
```

3.Append the header dir to configure.

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --includedir=/usr/include/tirpc/
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `/usr/include/rpc` folder does not include the rpc.h file and you already installied `libntirpc-dev`, try linking the header into the standard directory as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75118108/python-build-error-fatal-error-misc-abstract-atomic-h-no-such-file-or-directo/75119175#75119175)! Another **solution** I found, was to use `./configure CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/tirpc` described by @steeldriver in another answer here as a comment! The upvoted solution did not work for me unfortunately, even though it also includes the library directory path...

Answer (score 0):

Decision is simple. You need to put missing files from here `https://github.com/lattera/glibc/tree/master/sunrpc/rpc` to `/usr/include/rpc`
It's not secure, but working xD
[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nht2o.png)

Answer (score 0):

I did the snort configuration in Kali distribution

```
sp_rpc_check.c:32:10: fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #include <rpc/rpc.h>
```

---

Fix the problem as follows:

1. Search for a library that includes rpc (`apt-file search rpc/rpc.h`)
2. Installing (`apt-get install libntirpc-dev`)
3. Copying files from the `ntircp` folder to `rcp` folder
4. Run: `make`
5. Modifying the path of the file not found
6. Repeat the process until mistakes resolved

---

Ex. 1:

Copying files from ntirpc to rpc

```
sp_rpc_check.c:32:10: fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #include <rpc/rpc.h>
```

```
/include/ntirpc# cp rpc.h /usr/include/rpc

/snort_source/snort-2.9.18.1# make
```

Ex.2:

Editing types.h

```
/usr/include/rpc/types.h:189:10: fatal error: misc/abstract_atomic.h: No such file or directory
  189 | #include <misc/abstract_atomic.h>
```

Change the line from:

```
#include <misc/abstract_atomic.h>
```

to:

```
#include </usr/include/rpc/misc/abstract_atomic.h>
```

Then

```
/snort_source/snort-2.9.18.1# make
```

etc., ...

---

I modified the following files:

```
wait_queuq.h
clnt.h
rpc.h
pool_queue.h
svc.h
portable.h
types.h
```

as required by `make`.

Approx: 40 lines of code

Comment: Thanks. So following your instructions I fixed the rpc.h issue, and the abstract_atomic.h issue. what i am getting now is /usr/include/rpc/rpc-sn/rpc/svc.h:50:10: fatal error: reentrant.h: No such file or directory
   50 | #include "reentrant.h".     The reentrant.h file exists in the correct folder. it is referred to in the svc.h file etc in the following way: #include "reentrant.h" whereas most others are not in quotes. I have tried giving it a path , removing quotes,  using <reentrant.h> or even commenting it out, online for help, but none of these fix the problem.... any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem but got no help all over the internet then i figure out it myself. basically the file are there but somehow the snort looking in some other directories.
so all the files needed are placed in /usr/include/ntirpc/
but you have to copy each file accordingly to its own directories

for example to solve the first error you need to copy the file in the dir /usr/include/ntirpc/rpc/rpc.h to the dir /usr/include/rpc/

that will solve the first error but there are alot of other errors coming up in the installation but the same process.

if the error is misc/anyfile then copy the file from /usr/include/ntirpc/misc/  to the location /usr/incldue/misc

if the erroor says anyfile.h  remember to just copy it into the /usr/include/

Answer (score -1):

Ask the packaging system:

```
dpkg -S /usr/include/rpc/rpc.h
```

That will tell you which package provides `/usr/include/rpc/rpc.h`. Install that package. Read `man dpkg`.

Comment: So I get : no path found matching pattern /usr/include/rpc/rpc.h

Comment: Google suggested :https://github.com/lxi-tools/liblxi/issues/8 where is dicussed so I tried :     sudo dpkg -S /usr/include/tirpc/rpc/rpc.h, which returned: 
libtirpc-dev:amd64: /usr/include/tirpc/rpc/rpc.h
But: sudo apt-get install libtirpc-dev
....
libtirpc-dev is already the newest version (1.3.1-1build1).
libtirpc-dev set to manually installed.

0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 7 not to upgrade.

Comment: @omboidal if `rpc.h` is in a subdirectory you may need to pass the include path to the build process explicitly. The details will depend on exactly how it's written but you could try `./configure CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/tirpc` for example

Comment: @steeldriver , thank you , I tried your suggestion. The command completed ok, but still the  snort configuration  stops at the same point. Any suggestions are appreciated Thanks

Comment: Correct way to "Ask the packaging system" is https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=rpc.h or `sudo apt-get install apt-file; sudo apt-file update; apt-file search rpc/rpc.h` .