# Trying to install snort on a vmware ubuntu linux 22.04.3

Tags: vmware, snort

I'm following the [directions on this website here](https://upcloud.com/resources/tutorials/install-snort-ubuntu) on a google search on installing snort but these instructions don't work at all, i keep getting errors with configuring snort like `fatal error no such file in directory` whenever I run `./configure --enable-sourcefire && make && sudo make install`

I reran the steps multiple times, and these instructions just suck if I follow them and just get errors back.

Here's a picture of the error I'm getting on my Linux VMware when running the command.

[image]

> ./configure --enable-sourcefire && make && sudo make install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360945/fatal-error-rpc-rpc-h-no-such-file-or-directory)